# HTMX form submission with a table

Tags: flask, jinja2, htmx

I am trying to use the [Click to Edit](https://htmx.org/examples/click-to-edit/) example with HTMX, by using a table.

Each row (`<tr>`) is a database record that looks like this:

```
<tr hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">
<form>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{row.name}}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="{{row.email}}"></td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn" hx-put="/edit/{{row.id}}">Update<buttun>
          <button class="btn" hx-get="/view/{{row.id}}">Cancel</button>
        </td>
</form>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately, when I print the request body with `request.form.keys` on my `flask` server, I see that that the request is empty (`[]`)

It seems like the button click did not trigger the form submission with all the input fields.

How can I make the button click trigger the form submission with all the fields populated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, just remembered: you are working with tables here.  Unfortunately tables are super picky about the elements inside them, and I bet form doesn't work where you put it.  If you inspect the DOM I bet you'll find that there isn't really a form element in there, so htmx isn't finding it to include the inputs.

You'll need to rework this to include the values in a different way, for example using `hx-include`.

Something like this:

```html
<tr hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{row.name}}"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="{{row.email}}"></td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn" hx-put="/edit/{{row.id}}"
                  hx-include="closest tr">
              Update
          <button>
          <button class="btn" hx-get="/view/{{row.id}}">Cancel</button>
        </td>
</tr>
```

If you are willing to switch from table rows to divs, the original code you had should work fine.

This is an unfortunate situation where tables are not very flexible.

*update*: @guettli reminded me that you can include any element and it will include all inputs below it, so you can just use `closest tr` in your `hx-include` attribute.  Thanks!

Comment: I have place where I use htmx exactly like this: every TR tag behaves like a form. Works fine. If you want to provide oob data, then you might need htmx.config.useTemplateFragments

Comment: Thank you, the `hx-include` attribute worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what the request looks like from the chrome or firefox console?

This looks correct, in general.

Comment: The error is on the server side, the email and name fields do not get posted to the server